# Why my lightbox read can't this property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a photo gallery with [lightgallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) and [cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) using together, cycle is a carousel plugin, lightgallery is a lightbox gallery.

so when I click any image on carousel than it's image is opening on lightbox and I want to tell you everything works very well until you click any category on carousel.so I want to bother you about this problem

After you click any category the lightbox is not opening if you are click image on carousel and see error on console.

plugin gives me this erros

```
lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0…:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 's' of undefined
    at new c (lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0…:10)
    at Function.<anonymous> (lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0…:5)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at b.build (lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0…:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0…:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

[image]

for two weeks I'm trying to solve this problem

[please click to demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/WjOEeE)

or

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  options = {
    next: "#single-right",
    log: false,
    fx: "fade",
    caption: ".cycle-caption",
    captionTemplate: "{{title}}",
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pager: "#single-pager",
    pagerTemplate: "<img class='lazyload' data-src='{{exthumbimage}}' width='70' height='70'>",
    prev: "#single-left",
    slides: "div[data-hidden='false']"
  }

  function generateSlider(opt) {
    $("#myCarousel").cycle(opt);
  }

  generateSlider(options);

  $('#myCarousel').lightGallery({
    selector: "div[data-hidden='false']",
    exThumbImage: "data-exthumbimage",
    loadYoutubeThumbnail: true,
    youtubeThumbSize: 'default',
    loadVimeoThumbnail: true,
    vimeoThumbSize: 'thumbnail_medium',
  });



  $("#filter li").on("click", function() {
    var activeId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (activeId == "show-all") {
      $(".item").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    } else {
      $(".item").attr("data-hidden", "true");
      $("div[data-id = '" + activeId + "']").attr("data-hidden", "false");
    }
    $("#myCarousel").cycle("destroy");
    options['pagerTemplate'] = "<img class='lazyload' data-src='{{children.0.src}}'  width='70' height='70'>"
    generateSlider(options);
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
.mySlideShow {
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.item img {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#single-pager img {
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

#filter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 100;
}

#filter li {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 12px;
}

.cycle-caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

div[data-hidden='true'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/latest/css/lightgallery.css'>

<div class="mySlideShow">
  <div id="myCarousel">
    <div class="item" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/49a/massive-gear-1255802.jpg" data-exthumbimage="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/fa7/my-ride-1552678.jpg" data-id="animals" data-hidden="false" data-title="image 1">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/f7a/gear-1462890.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/7ae/autos-1194364.jpg" data-exthumbimage="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/5f6/kaputtes-auto-1564173.jpg" data-id="sports" data-hidden="false" data-title="image 2">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/20e/some-grill-1450817.jpg" />
    </div>


    <div class="item" data-src="https://vimeo.com/1084537" data-exthumbimage="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-y-2.jpg" data-id="natural" data-hidden="false" data-title="this is the video">
      <img class="lazyload" data-src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/c23/cat-1396828.jpg" />
    </div>

    <div id="single-pager">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="filter">
    <li id="animals">Animals</li>
    <li id="sports">Sports</li>
    <li id="natural">Natural</li>
    <li id="show-all">All</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cycle-caption"></div>
</div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lightgallery@1.3.5,lg-fullscreen@1.0.1,lg-hash@1.0.1,lg-pager@1.0.1,lg-share@1.0.1,lg-thumbnail@1.0.1,lg-video@1.0.1,lg-autoplay@1.0.1'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/3.0.0/lazysizes.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: The codepen doesn't throw the error.

Comment: @Phix click on ALL and then on image....

Comment: Hi @Phix first click any category for example natural and then click carousel image

Comment: so how can I fix the error ? and if I'm tring to run jquery code before loaading jquery.min.js than why cylce2 works ? thanks for replying

Comment: my scripts loading from cdn but this is my project: https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/MmvgPa

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu click any category on carousel for example natural or all and after click category than click my carousel image..you can see error on console

Comment: I got your error. It's not finding property `s`, not `$`, as I initially thought. Has to do with the lightbox plugin. Most likely you're using it other than it was intended. I guess someone needs to read the docs :)

Comment: I read docs but I updated my js with new but nothihg change..and if I don't use thumbnail.js my lightbox works but I need to use with thumbnail.js you can check it ot .js files on codepen

Comment: my english is not enough to understand sorry

Comment: It only breaks after using the filter. I guess you need to re-init the lightbox after you filter.

Comment: so how can I re-init lightbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter your carousel items, you break the lightbox instance. So what you need to do is:

1. Destroy the lightbox (if you don't, when you try to instantiate a new one it will recreate helper DOM elements needed for it to function, resulting in duplicate ID's and your lightbox will break). You need to call

```js
$('#myCarousel').data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
```

Without the `true` parameter, it's not properly destroyed, it's just closed (in case it's open).

2. Filter the slider.
3. Create a new lightbox.

Working example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRemwV

Doc ref: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/docs/api.html#methods

Comment: I am thankful to you so I can't tell you how happy I am it's great and it works very well

Comment: I will create again to look your project to understand thank you so much @Andrei